# MySql selecting ids from two different tables by other elements then ids

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `tableA` and `tableB`, both of them have fields `id, code, validFrom` and `validUntil`. I am trying to get ids from both of the tables in witch `tableA.code = tableB.code`, `tableA.validFrom = tableB.validFrom` and `tableB.validUntil = Null && tableA.validUntil != Null`.
I tried a select with inner join

```
Select a.id, b.id from tableA as a
inner join tableB as b ON 
    (a.code = b.code and a.validFrom = b.validFrom)
where b.validUntil is Null and a.validFrom != Null
```

But I am getting 0 results with this.
Tables example

```
TableA
id | code |  validFrom  | validUntil | Extra
---------------------------------------------
 1 | ABCD | 2010-01-01  | 2016-01-01 | NULL
 2 | EFA  | 2010-01-01  | 2015-01-01 | 12
 3 | FAS  | 2012-01-01  | 2017-01-01 | 13
```

And

```
TableB
id | code |  validFrom  | validUntil | Extra
---------------------------------------------
 1 | EFA  | 2010-01-01  | NULL       |  12
 2 | ABCD | 2010-01-01  | NULL       |  NULL
 3 | FAS  | 2012-01-01  | 2017-01-01 |  13
```

So result should be

```
TableA.id | TableB.id
---------------------
     1    |    2
     2    |    1
```

EDIT:

```
Select a.id, b.id from tableA as a
left join tableB as b ON 
    a.code = b.code 
    and a.validFrom = b.validFrom
    and a.Extra = b.Extra
where b.validUntil is Null 
and a.validFrom is not Null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IS NOT NULL` instead of `!= null`. You don't use equality operator with `NULL` values in DB. Change your below condition

```
and a.validFrom != Null
```

To this

```
and a.validFrom is not Null
```

Again, use a `LEFT JOIN` instead like

```
Select a.id, b.id from tableA as a
left join tableB as b ON 
    a.code = b.code 
    and a.validFrom = b.validFrom
where b.validUntil is Null 
and a.validFrom is not Null
```

Comment: Yeah my bad forgot to write it here like that to used to Java

Comment: Yes this is working, but im not getting all of the ids, im getting some of them

Comment: @LukasKarmanovas, so you want all ids matching that join condition?

Comment: But i think i know why its not working, i have one more element on witch I am trying to join `Extra` and some of the times it can be NULL on both tables, I am guessing that it null = null in join is not working like that

Comment: I have edited my question, as I mentioned I think that the problem may be with Extra being null, could that be possible?

Comment: about your question yes I want all the ids that match this join condition, but the match should be 1 to 1 because there isn't two elements with the same `validFrom` date, `code` and `extra`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah what I wanted to do was similar to what @Rahul said

```
Select a.id, b.id from tableA as a
left join tableB as b ON 
    a.code = b.code 
    and a.validFrom = b.validFrom
where b.validUntil is Null 
and a.validFrom is not Null
and (a.Extra = b.Extra or (a.Extra is NULL and b.Extra is NULL) )
```